# Flutter: create a TextField that accepts 4 numbers and formats it to hour:minute (HH:MM)?

Tags: flutter, dart, time, formatting

I want a TextField what opens the keyboard and the user has to tap 4 (or 3 if possible, when the hour is between 01-09).

The TextField onChange method should format it into a good looking HH:MM format.

So far I have this:

```
TextField(
   controller: _controller,
   style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 24,
           ),
   onChanged: (value) {},
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
)
```

Tried with regex but it does not let me to type anything:

```
TextField(
   controller: _controller,
   style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 24,
           ),
   onChanged: (value) {},
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
           FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?\$")),
           ],
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :
Also add intl: ^0.17.0 import this package for date format

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class MyData extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDataState createState() => _MyDataState();
}

class _MyDataState extends State<MyData> {

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final formatter = DateFormat('HH:mm a');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                ],
                controller: _controller,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And what to do with the `formatter`?

Comment: yes, the code does not use the formatter at all...